# How to get the first_name via graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get the picture with this code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture
```

but this doesn't work:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/userid/first_name
```

How can I get user's name ?

Answer (score 12):

You cannot get `first_name` like you are getting picture.

https://graph.facebook.com/userid/?fields=first_name

will get

```
{
   "first_name": "Jashwant",
   "id": "1137725463"
}
```

Then you can get `first_name` by any json parser.

Here's the **GIVE_ME_THE_CODE** version,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/jashwantsingh?fields=first_name',function(data){
        $('<p>' + data.first_name + '<p>').appendTo('body');
    })
 })

</script>
</head> 
<body> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I can't show it directly in the html code because it is in jsons :(

Comment: You can use FBML but its deprecated and will not work after 1st of june 2012. If you want it for just 12 days, I can share the code :)

Comment: how can I parse the json ? :D

Comment: but do I have to do first an http request to get the name in json?

Comment: I've updated the code. Do look at it. Mark as answer, if it helps you :)

Answer (score 3):

I have answer you this question here:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10663413/how-to-print-all-friendss-name/10663570#10663570

To get current user name you can make an FQL call:

```
FB.api({ method: 'fql.query', query: 'SELECT uid, first_name FROM user WHERE uid = me()' }, function(response) {
    var user = response[0];
    alert(user.first_name);
});
```

Also you can make a Graph API call:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=first_name', function(response) {
    alert(response.first_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know about implementation of facebook-api-graph. i used the java language to get the first name and we get the response from facebook as response.getBody()

This response will contain the data in json data format.

you can look at the below question.

[how to parse this json data to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607119/how-to-parse-this-json-data-to-java)