# org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json

I get an error when I try to get a JSON object from server after get all objects and put into JSON array:

```
JSONObject object = null;
try {
     object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code returns:

```
W/System.err: **org.json.JSONException**: 
Value {"keywords":"","autor":"","resposta_complete":"Incomplete","revisor2":"","referencias":"","revisor3":"","revisor1":"","setor_pergunta":"","pergunta_anterior":"","resposta_curta":"","resposta_longa":"","record_id":"178","data_resposta":"2016-10-17","imagem":"","class_pergunta":"Nao se trata de uma pergunta, ou ela esta ininteligivel.","revisor_externo":"","pergunta_revisada":""} 
at 167 of type org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONObject
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.populate(LoadData.java:206)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.doInBackground(LoadData.java:138)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.doInBackground(LoadData.java:63)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.populate(LoadData.java:210)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.doInBackground(LoadData.java:138)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at ft.projetorisadinha.classes.LoadData$Load.doInBackground(LoadData.java:63)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-17 17:32:34.660 15402-15453/ft.projetorisadinha W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

When I run that in API 23, everything is ok. Is it an issue from API support? How can I solve that?

**UPDATE**

Inside my activity:

```
private org.json.simple.JSONArray array_obj = null;
```

Inside my code, here is where I parse JSON:

```
if (reader == null)
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser();
    if (array_obj == null) {
        array_obj = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) parser_obj.parse(line);
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(array_obj);
    }
}
```

and here is my JSON imports:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
 try {
    object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update**

You just have to change :

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

To :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Do the same with `JSONArray` and `JSONException`

Comment: No, the same error yet. But I think it is a cast error: note -> type org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Use `import org.json.JSONObject;` instead

Comment: I'm using that. I'll update my question with more information

Comment: Yes you have to import `org.json.JSONObject` instead of `org.json.simple.JSONObject`

Comment: I'm using org.json.simple.JSONObject, but inside my code I have a parser. See my update, please

Comment: I tested your edit. But after that, I can't use functions like jsonObject.getString(String name); for example, and I can't get data from server...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem changing some parts of my code:

Instead of:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONParser parser_obj = new JSONParser();
    if (array_obj == null) {
        array_obj = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) parser_obj.parse(line);
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(array_obj);
    }
}
```

I simple wrote:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(line);
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);
```

*Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442529/3186711) question